# Invoking SignalR method after receiving message in javascript client

Tags: javascript, .net-core, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying to use javascript to call a function on my SignalR hub after receiving a message. I know I am receiving my message in my javascript client, but invoke is not working.

This is my javascript code:

```
    connection.on("ReceiveResetCounter", function() => {

    connection.invoke("resetCounter");
```

});

And this is my hub method:

```
public async Task resetCounter()
    {
        Counter = 0;
    }
```

Does anyone know what could cause this to happen? Any help appreciated.

Edit:

I am calling start like this (and the invoke used there works fine):

```
connection.start().then(
function ()
{
    connection.invoke("SomeOtherMethod").catch(
        function (err)
        {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });
}).catch(
function (err)
{
    return console.error(err.toString());
```

});

Answer (score 0):

> I am receiving my message in my javascript client, but invoke is not working.

Based on the code you shared, I did a test with my SignalR hub, which work well for me.

```
connection.on("ReceiveResetCounter", () => {
    connection.invoke("resetCounter");
});
```

Test Result

[image]

To troubleshoot the issue, please check if you call the `start` method on the HubConnection after using `on` method to define the method on JavaScript client side.

```
connection.on("ReceiveResetCounter", () => {
    connection.invoke("resetCounter");
});

connection.start().then(function () {

//...
```

Besides, please try to turn on [JavaScript client logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-5.0#javascript-client-logging) and check logs about connections and activities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my code with where I am starting the connection and I added logs to the call. I see the connection being opened and no errors on invoke but the call still doesn't work

Comment: Have you checked if `connection.invoke("resetCounter");` is executed? And if you invoke another hub method in that callback function, does it work well?